# Manager does not have permission to manage_users in acl_users/source_users

Tags: plone

I'm trying to cleanup a Plone site that has been handed to me, but I'm not allowed to start from scratch (we're not just there yet).

I've been asked to change the password of several users, and I found myself locked out, even with the ZMI user: When I click over /plone-site/acl_users/source_users in the ZMI I get an `Unauthorized` error!

So, I think this is either:

- Some plugin like LDAP (although is not been used) is messing with my users source.
- Someone messed up the permissions.

Any ideas of how to fix this? (For the time being I have instructed users to regain access by using the "Forgotten password" form, but in the future I may need to have access to this object for some other purpose.)

**Updated 2013-01-14**

As asked by @aclark, I'm providing a full traceback with `verbose-security=on`:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 324, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 361, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplateFile, line 130, in _exec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 80, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 113, in pt_render
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 819, in do_loop_tal
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 682, in setRepeat
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: manage_users
   - Line 31, Column 1
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:'here/listUserInfo'>
   - Names:
      {'container': <UserManager at /ca/acl_users/source_users>,
       'context': <UserManager at /ca/acl_users/source_users>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7f4c7f84aad0>,
       'here': <UserManager at /ca/acl_users/source_users>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': ()},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0xbf67418>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://intranet.lahavane.com/ca/acl_users/source_users/manage_users>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <PageTemplateFile at /ca/acl_users/source_users/manage_users>,
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 149, in _eval 
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 124, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 76, in boboAwareZopeTraverse
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 310, in restrictedTraverse
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 245, in unrestrictedTraverse
   - __traceback_info__: ([], 'listUserInfo')
  Module AccessControl.ImplPython, line 729, in guarded_getattr
  Module AccessControl.ImplPython, line 671, in aq_validate
  Module AccessControl.ImplPython, line 565, in validate
  Module AccessControl.ImplPython, line 463, in validate
  Module AccessControl.ImplPython, line 810, in raiseVerbose
Unauthorized: Your user account does not have the required permission.  Access to 'listUserInfo' of (UserManager at /ca/acl_users/source_users) denied. Your user account, admin, exists at /acl_users. Access requires Manage_users_Permission, granted to the following roles: []. Your roles in this context are ['Authenticated', 'Manager', 'Owner'].
```

The last line is the enlightening one: There's no role who can do what I'm trying to do. Now the question would be how to fix this. Another question (which we might not answer) is how does this came to happen.

Comment: Do you have the same error, when accessing the user-list via the controlpanel: /plone-site/@@usergroup-userprefs ?

Comment: 1.) Can you change the passwords via the Plone-UI then? 2.) Did you try to use an emergency-user and does the error occur then? (In order to exclude someone disgranted privileges to your user) 3.) Is it sure the user-management is plain Plone one, no external services connected?

Comment: @IdaEbkes I added an emergency user and the problem persists. The message still is: Your user account does not have the required permission. Access to 'listUserInfo' of (UserManager at /ca/acl_users/source_users) denied. Your user account, god, exists at /acl_users. Access requires Manage_users_Permission, granted to the following roles: []. Your roles in this context are ['Authenticated', 'Manager']. --- The issue here is that Manage_users_Permission is not granted to any roles.

Comment: Is there a difference when you login as siteadmin, respectively as zopeadmin? (note: to logout as zopeadmin you have to actual close the browser)

Comment: @IdaEbkes The siteadmin has no privileges at the root level, so I can't traverse to /acl_user with the siteadmin user. Is the zopeadmin user who is being kicked out.

Comment: The request-variable in your traceback indicates, that you were trying to access acl_users of a plonesite ('ca'), not of the zoperoot. Try to access it with a plonesiteadmin and tell us if the error still occurs.

Comment: @IdaEbkes It fails nonetheless with my plone-level admin account : Your user account does not have the required permission. Access to 'listUserInfo' of (UserManager at /ca/acl_users/source_users) denied. Your user account, manu, exists at /ca/acl_users. Access requires Manage_users_Permission, granted to the following roles: []. Your roles in this context are ['Authenticated', 'Manager', 'Member', 'Reader'].

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough time to go further with this. But are you ok with the site right now or does this need to be solved urgently? Hope for you, that you get the privilege to upgrade/migrate, soon :)

Comment: @IdaEbkes Thanks anyway for all your support. Currently, we have ease all the problems. We're looking forward to upgrade to the latest version of Plone; but since the cause of our problems seems to manyfold, we're carefully planning this step. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't guess**. First, remove `Unauthorized` from the list of ignored exceptions in `Site Setup -> Errors`:

[image]

Then `Save`. Next, make sure `verbose-security` is enabled in the **instance section** of your `buildout.cfg` file e.g.:

```
  [instance]
  recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
  verbose-security = on
```

(Run buildout after setting this.)

Now visit **/plone-site/acl_users/source_users**, and return to `Site Setup -> Errors` to see the actual error.

Comment: I'd have done that before posting this question. That's how I knew admin is the user being denied access. Showed in http://twitpic.com/bn2wds

Comment: In order to get help with a problem like this we need to see the full traceback. You've not show us anything yet that can help us help you.

Comment: I have updated the question to provide the traceback. I don't see anything strange; but you might see something I don't. Do you need anything else? I have tried to peek into `*__roles__` attributes on the console; but also nothing has helped me yet.

Comment: And I have updated my answer to include the verbose-security setting :-). Your traceback does not appear to include the "extra" information provided by verbose-security when it is enabled (not 100% sure about this though, there may be cases where verbose-security does not help even when enabled)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was temporarily disconnected. I have set up the verbose-security flag on, and I'm updating the question. The only differences is in the last line, that now states that: `Access to 'listUserInfo' of (UserManager at /ca/acl_users/source_users) denied. Your user account, admin, exists at /acl_users. Access requires Manage_users_Permission, granted to the following roles: []. Your roles in this context are ['Authenticated', 'Manager', 'Owner'].`

Comment: It says that no role has the required permission. The `Manage users` permission should be set on the Zope root to `Manager`. Go to `manage_access` on your zope root and check that the `Manager` has this permission. Maybe this is patched when creating a plone site - did you create any plone site on this instance with the plone wizard? (e.g. when using ZEO mount point this is not necessary)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to manage the plone-users with a Zope-Application level user (the user is listet at `/acl_users/users/manage_users` on zope level - not in the acl_users on plone level).
If the user somehow has no Manager role on plone level, it is not possible to manage the plone users.

Possible reasons could be:

- Your Zope-level user has no longer the "Manager" role on Zope level (the user should have `Manager` role under `/acl_users/roles/manage_roles`).
- You have a user with the same ID as the zope-level user on plone-level, but without `Manager` role. The user would either be listed under `/plone-site/acl_users/source_users` - which you cannot check because of the `Unauthorized` error - or by another PAS plugin such as LDAP. Giving the user the `Manager` role on plone level too would fix the problem without the need of deleting the user from plone level acl_users.

I propose creating an emergency user:

- go to the terminal on your server (e.g. ssh)
- run `bin/instance adduser emergency secret` (bin/instance may vary depending on type the installation)
- You now have a new user with name "emergency" and password "secret", registered on zope-leve l (`/acl_users/users/manage_users`) with `Manager` role (`acl_users/roles/manage_roles`).
- Using this user you can fix the other manager user and after fixing it remove the emergency user.

When having the same user registered on Zope's acl_users and on Plone's acl_users with different roles you may get some strange effects. Depending on the current authentication method (e.g. Zope-level basic authentication or Plone-level cookie auth) you may have different privileges with the same user.